# Adding extra files to your app in Android

Tags: android, c++, qt, qt-creator

I am using Qt 5.2, QtCreator.

I have written an app and I also have an executable file that I can run on Android but I would like it so that when I install my app the executable can be called there to so I want it to be included with it for example when I look in the file `/data/data/com.example.myapp/files` the executable will be in there.

Does anybody know how to do this?

Comment: Is it really "when I install my app" or "when my app is installed"? And how does 'an executable file that can can be run on Android' look like? Not an app? You can include any file you want in the assets folder and copy to that files dir at -first- startup.

Comment: @greenapps I don't know what your first question is asking but an executable on android looks just the same as one on linux it's not really an app. You can run it was ./ just as you would in linux. I didn't really need to specify that it as an executable I just needed to know how get a file into my app. The assets folder seems like what I could be looking for. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Within your development folder you'll find \android\assets - just put the executable file into that folder and add these to your .pro :

```
deployment.files += program
deployment.path = /assets
INSTALLS += deployment
```

But the files in assets are readonly. So you should first copy it to some other location:

```
QFile dfile("assets:/program");
if (dfile.exists())
{
     dfile.copy("./program");
     QFile::setPermissions("./program",QFile::WriteOwner | QFile::ReadOwner);
}
```

Now you have access to the file and you can run it.

Comment: is this something that works on qt 5.2 because after trying the first chunk of code I cant seem to find the executable file when I use adb shell it search through it. I even ran a find | grep for it and I have the phone rooted.